# Jquery .click function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a tab and append some text in it

```
$("#tabcontent").append('<p id="c'+count+'"><table> <tr>Tab Content '+count+'<br><span id="addColumns" style="cursor:pointer;">Add Columns</span></p>');
```

there is an id `addColumns` I write a function for this id

`$('#addColumns').click(function(){
        $("#tabcontent").html('');
    });`

When I click on `Add Columns` Nothing is happening...

Comment: Can you put up your html/js on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: 1. i think u r using update panel..
2. may be ur addcolumn is server control...

as per @gideon if u put ur code it easy to solve...

Comment: It is working in JSFiddle. See this Link:     
http://jsfiddle.net/sfWxJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is not in DOM when page loaded, so this is future element that's why it's not working. you have to use `.live()`

```
$('#addColumns').live('click', function(){ $("#tabcontent").html(''); });
```

or as per jQuery 1.7

use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click','#addColumns', function(){
        $("#tabcontent").html('');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

let's just fix that html structure you got and try it again.

```
<p id="c'+count+'">
    <table> 
        <tr>Tab Content '+count+'
            <br>
            <span id="addColumns" style="cursor:pointer;">Add Columns</span>
</p>
```

Besides - you really want to clear the element in which you clicked the span?

**EDIT:**
That is your html code, not the one you should use. Try a td-tag inside your row and try to close your tags.